# Getting the Correct Time from A TimeStamp

Tags: android, time, calendar, android-calendar

I am recieving the following long 1389967092 as a time stamp. This should represent ...

GMT: Fri, 17 Jan 2014 13:58:12 GMT

OR

My time zone: 1/17/2014 2:58:12 PM GMT+1

However I am in GMT+1 but the time I want to show is the GMT representation. I am trying the following:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(timeStamp);
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    Log.d(Point.class.getSimpleName(), date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes());
```

But this prints 12:58

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT - RESPONSE TO ANSWER**

This the code I am using it prints 1969-12-13 10:54:48

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(1389967092*1000);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    Log.d(Point.class.getSimpleName(), sdf.format(calendar.getTime));
```

Comment: If your timestamp is a UNIX timestamp, it is in seconds not miliseconds, which calendar uses.

Answer (score 2):

The default `Calendar.getInstance` returns the time according to your device's timezone. However, you may request a different timezone like this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

---

In order to print your current time according to different timezone(s) then you may use `SimpleDateFormat`. For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Log.d(TAG, sdf.format(new Date()));
```

Comment: this prints out 12:58 also

Comment: I logged it like this Log.d(TAG, sdf.format(cal.getDate()); and it returns a date from 1969

Comment: then it means your time stamp is from 1969. Use the correct time and it should work.

Comment: the problem was with casting int to long, I don't really understand why but it seems to be working now. I will write up an answer

Comment: change `1389967092*1000` to `1389967092*1000L`. note the **L** at end of 1000. It will keep the conversion as **Long**

Comment: yup thats what I said ;)